# Breeze and ng-animate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze, single-page-application

Is it possible to use [breeze](http://www.breezejs.com/) with ng-animate?

I can't find an example on the net. Just executing a query and applying data doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

See John Papa's Pluralsight course "[Building Apps with Angular and Breeze](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/build-apps-angular-breeze)"

Comment: breeze and animation are unrelated. Search the web for examples of ngAnimate in connection with any async operation.